# Can you negate an adventure spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I [Negate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNegate%5d) the instant/sorcery part of an adventure spell?

Say, someone casts Stomp from bonecrusher giant. Can I negate it?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is nothing special about the Adventure half of an Adventurer card while it is on the stack. Comprehensive rules 715.3b:

> While on the stack as an Adventure, the spell has only its alternative characteristics.

Countering the Adventure half of an Adventurer card is often a very good play to make as the countered spell goes to its owner's graveyard, not into exile where the non-Adventure half of the card can be cast - e.g. if you counter Stomp, its owner does *not* get to cast Bonecrusher Giant from exile.

A small note on terminology: the *spell* does not have halves. An Adventurer card has alternative characteristics, and if cast with those alternative characteristics it is then a spell with solely those characteristics - e.g. what is on the stack is either the instant spell Stomp or the creature spell Bonecrusher Giant, not a split object with both sets of characteristics. This may seem pedantic but it can be important - for example, you cannot use [Essence Scatter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEssence%20Scatter%5d) to counter Stomp, because it is not a creature spell.

Comment: Hmm, but as a card, it has all the characteristics of both options right? Ie, it is a creature card and an instant card? So, if there was some spell that let you exile a noncreature card from someone's hand, library, graveyard, or stack, then it wouldn't let you exile stomp?

Comment: @WillChen The very first point of [Throne of Eldraine release notes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/throne-eldraine-release-notes-2019-09-20) answers that (in the negative).

Comment: @WillChen See also CR 715.4 "In every zone except the stack, and while on the stack not as an Adventure, an adventurer card has only its normal characteristics." - "normal characteristics" here refers to the non-Adventure half of the card.