# Can I cast an Adventure spell with Codie in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm playing a [Codie, Vociferous Codex](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Codie%2C%20Vociferous%20Codex) deck and was wondering if Adventure spells synergizes with codie.

### Question:

- Does casting the adventure half of the spells count as casting a permanent spell? Or can I cast adventure spells when codie's in play.

  I'm assuming casting the adventure spell is viable when codie's in
  play because [you can negate](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51515/can-you-negate-an-adventure-spell) adventure spells.
- If Q1 is true, while the card is "adventuring", and when codie is in play, can I play the other half of the adventure spell? Does playing the adventured permanent count as casting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does casting the adventure half of the spells count as casting a permanent spell?

No. [Comprehensive Rule 716.3a](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020220429.pdf):

> When casting an adventurer card as an Adventure, only the alternative characteristics are evaluated to see if it can be cast.

where "alternative characteristics" refers to the "adventure half" of the card. Assuming the alternative characteristics are of a non-permanent (which is the case for all Adventurer cards as of May 2022), you can cast it while Codie is in play.

> can I play the other half of the adventure spell? Does playing the adventured permanent count as casting?

No and yes respectively. CR 716.3d:

> Instead of putting a spell that was cast as an Adventure into its owner’s graveyard as it resolves, its controller exiles it. For as long as that card remains exiled, that player may cast it. It can’t be cast as an Adventure this way

(Assuming the non-Adventure half of the card is a permanent. Once again, that is the case for all Adventurer cards as of May 2022)