# Codie with adventure spells

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So when you activate codie's ability by casting a sorcery or instant and start revealing cards from the top of your deck, if you reveal a permanent spell with adventure, are you able to cast the adventure or does the card get skipped entirely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adventure spells and Codie](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57392/adventure-spells-and-codie)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate. This question asks about Codie's activated ability; the other one only deals with Codie's static ability.

Comment: I know from past experience that for example some spells that let you cast instants and sorceries from the grave also let you adventure cards in your grave so I'm wondering if technically codie would let you cast them in the same manner. Since technically the adventure is a non permanent spell, wouldn’t you have the option of casting it since it's alternative spell fits codies restriction.

Comment: @CyberTechIndustries It’s a tricky one… 601.3e makes it clear that you can cast an adventure spell if you’re given an effect of “you may cast an instant or sorcery spell…”. But Codie requires you to exile an instant or sorcery card, before you stop exiling cards.

Comment: @PhilipKendall reading that linked question and answer, it doesn't answer the question asked here

Comment: I see why there was confusion because both questions deal with Codie and adventures. But there are 3 separate interactions that exist between Codie and adventure cards; the other question asks about 2 of those things, while this question asks about the third. There is no overlap.

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to cast an adventure this way.

> 715.4. In every zone except the stack, and while on the stack not as an Adventure, an adventurer card has only its normal characteristics.

So the cards that have been exiled with Codie's activated ability are in the Exile zone, and thus are permanent cards, not instant or sorcery cards.

Codie's "you may cast that card" would actually allow you to cast an adventure if "that card" were an adventure, because rule 601.3e allows you to consider alternative characteristics as part of determining if you can cast a spell:

> 601.3e Some rules and effects state that an alternative set of characteristics or a subset of characteristics are considered to determine if a card or copy of a card is legal to cast. These alternative characteristics replace the object’s characteristics for this determination.

However, Codie will exile cards "until you exile an instant or sorcery card with lesser mana value", and an adventure card will never qualify as that, so you will keep exiling cards, and can only cast the last card you exiled ("that card"). From the original release notes about Adventure:

> For example, while it's in your graveyard, Giant Killer is a white creature card whose converted mana cost is 1. It can't be the target of the triggered ability of Mystic Sanctuary.